# How to call a column vector in for-loop to sort each column in a table?

Tags: for-loop, dolphindb

I would like to sort each column in a table using DolphinDB. Do you know how to call the column vector in for...loop?

I run the following scripts but raise an error:

```py
list_columnNames = df.columnNames()
for (i in list_char) {
    update df_s set rank_ = rank(i,,10) context by Month
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in the "i" in your code because it indicates a variable rather than a certain column.
You can use sqlUpdate to dynamically generate updated scripts.

```py
df_s = table(1 2 3 4 5 6 as val1, 2 1 3 4 7 6 as val2, take(2012.01M + 0..2, 6) as Month)
colNames = ["val1", "val2"]
for(colName in colNames) {
sqlUpdate(table=df_s, updates=sqlColAlias(makeCall(rank, sqlCol(colName), true, 10), "rank_" + colName), contextBy=sqlCol("Month")).eval()
}
```

The output is shown in the picture.

[image]